# looping through a jade in a node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i need to loop through this jade segment:

```
.question.clearfix
                .que-no
                  | 1
                .que-text
                  | For maximum team productivity, a leader should:
                .clr
                .radio-vertical.left-offset2
                  label.radio.clearfix
                    input(name='Option_01', type='radio', value='445_1512')
                    div
                      | Let the team members be in charge
                  label.radio.clearfix
                    input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                    div
                      | Closely monitor every team member's activities
                  label.radio.clearfix
                    input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                    div
                      | Be a source of help and support for the team, with minimal interference
                  label.radio.clearfix
                    input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                    div
                      | Check on the team's overall progress from time to time and encourage their suggestions
```

using for loop i tried this:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  .question.clearfix
                    .que-no
                      | 1
                    .que-text
                      | For maximum team productivity, a leader should:
                    .clr
                    .radio-vertical.left-offset2
                      label.radio.clearfix
                        input(name='Option_01', type='radio', value='445_1512')
                        div
                          | Let the team members be in charge
                      label.radio.clearfix
                        input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                        div
                          | Closely monitor every team member's activities
                      label.radio.clearfix
                        input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                        div
                          | Be a source of help and support for the team, with minimal interference
                      label.radio.clearfix
                        input(name='Option_01', type='radio')
                        div
                          | Check on the team's overall progress from time to time and encourage their suggestions
- }
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined !!

Comment: Copying the 2nd snippet into the [online demo](http://jade-lang.com/demo/) doesn't produce any indentation errors. Though, with the update to a `TypeError`, that seems to hint at issues with the code that's trying to render the template. Can you share a snippet of that?

Comment: the template renders just fine without the loop construct!!

Comment: without { and -} i get the same typeerror

Comment: Where in the rest of your template are you referring to `filename`? Are you overwriting a passed variable called `i` with your for-loop by any chance? Are you sure the error is caused by Jade?

Comment: is there a tool that can help me with fixing up the indentation thing>